# IOS: AutoLayout UITableView -> UITableViewCell not showing correct size

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

Basically i am trying to figure out why the cell does not go all the way to the end base on the device width. On iPhone6 it still show 320 in width instead of 375. Here http://1drv.ms/1E7Nrqp is a sample project i created.

Thanks,
Hoay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

         self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];


    }
    return self;
}
```

In TableViewCell.m write the above code